# How do you know what you've displayed is completely drawn on screen?

Tags: opengl, screen, swap, framebuffer, vsync

Displaying images on a computer monitor involves the usage of a graphic API, which dispatches a series of asynchronous calls... and at some given time, put the wanted stuff on the computer screen.

But, what if you are interested in knowing the ***exact*** CPU time at the point where the required image is fully drawn (and visible to the user)?

I really need to grab a CPU timestamp when everything is displayed to relate this point in time to other measurements I take.

Without taking account of the asynchronous behavior of the graphic stack, many things can get the length of the graphic calls to jitter:

- multi-threading;
- Sync to V-BLANK (unfortunately required to avoid some tearing);
- what else have I forgotten? :P

I target a solution on Linux, but I'm open to any other OS. I've already studied parts of the [xvideo extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_video_extension) for X.org server and the OpenGL API but I havent found an effective solution yet.

I only hope the solution doesn't involve hacking into video drivers / hardware!

Note: I won't be able to use the recent Nvidia G-SYNC thing on the required hardware. Although, this technology would get rid of some of the unpredictable jitter, I think it wouldn't completely solve this issue.

---

[OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval#GPU_vs_CPU_synchronization) suggests the following: "If GPU<->CPU synchronization is desired, you should use a high-precision/multimedia timer rather than glFinish after a buffer swap."

Does somebody knows how properly grab such a high-precision/multimedia timer value just after the swapBuffer call is completed in the GPU queue?

Comment: You have forgotten that GPUs are virtualized resources in modern operating systems. Microsoft Windows has a pretty sophisticated scheduler in WDDM (Windows Vista+'s display driver model), your application can be pre-empted by something that has higher GPU priority (e.g. the Desktop Window Manager). If you are truly writing software with real-time (in the traditional **latency / deadline sense** and not high framerate as this term is often simplified to mean) GPU requirements, then this is going to get in your way :-\

Comment: Yes, that's why I favored Linux for this application. Virtualization could still be a problem but at least, it's not a black box. To minimize this problem I disabled desktop composting extensions (Composite and AIGLX for ATI) to avoid indirect rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Recent OpenGL provides sync/fence objects. You can place sync objects in the OpenGL command stream and later wait for them to get passed. See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Object

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although as with a glFinish call, the only option currently available with fences is waiting for them in a blocking operation. Placing a fence after a swapBuffer call would unfortunately block the render loop, discarding any advantages of double buffering.

Comment: @Jonathan: Actually OpenGL calls will only block if the pipeline stalled and full. Stalling happens only when a synchronization point for an operation on the *back buffer* is reached, before the buffer swapped happened. The key words here are **"the back buffer"**, you can perfectly fine continue rendering stuff to framebuffers other than the to-be-swapped surface, like an FBO render buffer or texture attachment.