# How to implement OpenGL GPU to CPU synchronization

Tags: opengl, swap, framebuffer, synchronization, vsync

OpenGL Wiki tells something interesting regarding GPU/CPU synchronization in the last paragraph of the [Swap Interval](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval#GPU_vs_CPU_synchronization) topic page:

> If GPU<->CPU synchronization is desired, you should use a high-precision/multimedia timer rather than glFinish after a buffer swap.

`glFinish()` or `glFenceSync()` based approaches aren't working well, as suggested by the quoted text. I believe that those high-precision / multimedia timers are not part of the OpenGL Specification. So:

*Does anyone know how to use high-precision/multimedia timers in order to call some CPU code (perhaps grab a timestamp) immediately after the buffer swap on a V-Synched display?*

I target a solution written in C++ and compiled on Linux, but any library name, code bits or intuition would greatly help!

Comment: Why do you need to implement synchronization as such? The discussion of synchronization in the Swap Interval wiki page is primarily intended as a means of minimizing input latency. It would help if you explained what you were trying to do, simply telling us that something is not working well is not a lot to go on.

Comment: This question is related to this [one] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772758/how-do-you-know-what-youve-displayed-is-completely-drawn-on-screen)